# CSS link button animation on hover pushes content

Tags: html, css

I have a link button in a `div`:

```
  <div class="text-box">
    <h1 class="main-title">
      <span class="main-title--primary">outdoors</span>
      <span class="main-title--secondary">is where life happens</span>
    </h1>
    <a href="#" class="main-cta-btn">discover</a>
  </div>
```

And css property for it:

```
.main-cta-btn:link,
.main-cta-btn:visited {
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
  color: #28b485;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  animation: moveBottom 2s ease-in;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

When I try add hover affect to it with this code:

```
.main-cta-btn:hover,
.main-cta-btn:active {
  background: transparent;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

The link push up other `div` elements in the text-box `div`. How I can fix this push effect and I must say I have absolute positioning on `main-title` for centering it in the page.

`main-title` css property:

```
.text-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I would recommend to remove the state-dependent pseudo-classes `:link, :visited` for applying layout properties (in addition to the answer). And don’t forget to [provide a `:focus` style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus) as well. (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's this `border: 2px solid white;` added on hover who's causing the issue, by increasing the width and hight of the button. The trick is to have that border from the beginning but with a transparent colour, and just change the colour on hover.

```css
.main-cta-btn:link,
.main-cta-btn:visited {
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
  color: #28b485;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  animation: moveBottom 2s ease-in;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* Line I added */
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}

.main-cta-btn:hover,
.main-cta-btn:active {
  background: transparent;
  color: red; 
  /* Line I added */
  border-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.text-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-box">
    <h1 class="main-title">
      <span class="main-title--primary">outdoors</span>
      <span class="main-title--secondary">is where life happens</span>
    </h1>
    <a href="#" class="main-cta-btn">discover</a>
  </div>
```